# runtime permissions in MNC emulator not appearing

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mnc

My issue is that runtime permissions are not working on my app.  It is behaving as usual. Below is the emualator im using:
[image]

and here is my androidManifest target sdk levels:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

should i have the 23 to MNC or whats the issue ? The reason i know its not working is because i hold the internet permission and read external storage permission. i am able to see the admob ads right away without asking for internet permission (btw can you imagine how annoying that is, every app uses the internet and now there all going to ask for permission ).

Comment: `INTERNET` is not a `dangerous` permission, and so you do not need to ask for it via `requestPermissions()`.

Comment: so its only dangerous permissions that we need to ask for ?

Comment: Yes. Quoting [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html): "If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically. If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give approval to your app. "

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for. feel free to make a official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTERNET` is a `normal` permission. You do not need to use `requestPermissions()` for `normal` permissions, only `dangerous` ones. `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` *is* `dangerous`; I cannot comment on whether or not you need it for AdMob.